# Mat-toggle-slide Triggers

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

I have a regular mat-slide-toggle with a click event like below:

```html
<mat-slide-toggle (click)="do()" [(ngModel)]="checked"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

This component is triggered by both click and spacebar. But with the spacebar it doesn't trigger the click event. How can I do so?

And in terms of accessibility. It is right to trigger by spacebar and not with enter key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But with the spacebar it doesn't trigger the click event. How can I do so?

You should use `(change)="do()"` as the underlying component is an `input type="checkbox"`. This should cover all input types.

> And in terms of accessibility. It is right to trigger by spacebar and not with enter key?

Yes, a switch operates in the same way as a checkbox so the expected key is <kbd>Space</kbd>. [You can read more about expected behaviour of a `role="switch"` element on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/switch_role)

It is worth noting that if the underlying component for a `role="switch"` is a `<button>` then you can use `(click)="do()"` and it will work with <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well, but this isn't the case in the material library component (useful to know if you ever make your own though!).